# Названия трасс. Нужен ли дефис в номере автодороги? (М-1 или М1)

Tags: дефис

Подскажите, ставится ли дефис в номерах трасс? М-1 или М1? А-103 или А103? В официальных документах и на сайте Минтранса, например, пишут через дефис, но на дорожных знаках - без.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Названия трасс являются официально зарегистрированными идентификаторами: именами собственными. Поэтому пишутся они так, как указано в документах: заглавная буква классификации, дефис, номер. Опционально можно указать развернутый тип перед идентификатором (Автомобильная дорога, Федеральная автомобильная дорога, и т.д.), и дополнительное название в кавычках после ("Дон", "Кавказ", "Украина").

На знаках написание слитное, у чего есть несколько факторов.

Во-первых, это экономия места. Дефис не дает никакой информации, но его литерная площадка занимает в ширину порядка 60% высоты заглавной буквы. Меньше лишних символов—больше места для полезной информации.

Во-вторых, это безопасность. При перемещении на автомобиле, тем более на трассе, требуется воспринимать информацию со знаков не отвлекаясь от ведения автомобиля. Чем больше символов, тем больше визуальная загруженность знака и тем сложнее его быстро "прочесть".

В-третьих, это международная унификация. Хотя Венская конвенция о дорожных знаках и сигналах и не регулирует стиль написания, на практике европейские участники пишут названия маршрутов на знаках слитно.

Впрочем, замечу следующую технологическую/типографическую особенность: в Европе используют специфическое оформление с визуальным отделением буквы от номера дополнительным пространством, но без использования пробела. Как правило это достигается через использование особого шрифта, в котором глифы букв имеют увеличенное правое поле (например, для Великобритании см. The Traffic Signs Regulations and General Directions, Schedule 17, Part 3 и Part 4, где правое поле глифа M примерно в полтора раза больше левого).

Также хочу добавить ещё одно замечание, которое связано скорее с графическим дизайном, нежели с правописанием: в тексте книг, буклетов, и веб-страниц, обычно допускается писать название дороги слитно, если оформление имитирует дорожный знак с соответствующими цветами фона и текста. В этом случае номер маршрута как бы перестает быть частью текста (то есть перестает быть именем собственным) и становится графическим элементом документа.